# Sporting activities in Goa

Tags: planning, india, outdoor-activities, goa-india

Me along with my friends are planning to tour Goa on Sept 29-Oct2.

We are really interested in jet skiing, scuba diving, sailing and various such sporting activities. But, we are not aware of such places in Goa.

I would like to know the list of such activities and how to contact such organisations if any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Goa has a list of water sporting activities and most popular amongst them are Jet skiing, Parasailing, and banana ride. Scuba diving, however, is yet underdeveloped sport in Goa. Goa is more popular for its clubbing, relaxing, beautiful scenic beauty and it Susegadu (which means relaxed attitude in Goan language) attitude.

If you are interested in Scuba diving I would suggest you to visit Lakshwadeep Island on the west coast of India.

For more information, you can always visit these websites.

http://www.goa-tourism.com

http://www.tripraja.com

[Water Sports Price List - 2020](https://top10goa.com/things-to-do/top-10-watersports-activities-in-goa)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was able to fetch a lot of information by redirecting through different sites. Though a lot of details were provided about various sporting activities, no contact information were available for any of such clubs. Might be I will have to go to Goa and find them myself!

Comment: Contact info won't be necessary as any local person in Goa would know about it. North Goa beaches like Baga, Calangute and Anjuna are good beaches to hang around and the party hubs. Go there and explore it yourself. :)