# What local sporting events are available in Goa over late December?

Tags: india, sports-events, goa-india

I'm a keen runner/swimmer/cyclist and triathlete, and love taking part in events both off road and on. Currently planning a trip to Goa from December 15th till the New Year, and I was wondering what local events are available? I've managed to find the [Goa River Marathon](http://www.goarivermarathon.com/) although this is a little too early, and will sadly miss it.

I'm aware of another [sporting question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7836/sporting-activities-in-goa) being asked about Goa, but I feel my question differs enough.

Answer (score 2):

While you probably need to qualify to enter, if you're interested in spectating, the [2013 Losophone Games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_Lusophony_Games) will be taking place in Goa during November, and there may well be follow-on events after that closer to your arrival.

Otherwise I'm afraid your question might be considered a bit too localised :/ Hope that is at least of interest, though!